# cannot import name '_endpoint_from_view_func' from 'flask.helpers' in python

Tags: python, flask

I ran the same code on Ubuntu with no problem, but ran it on Windows10 with problems. I also installed Flask.
My windows environment is configured as follows:

```
$ pip --version
pip 21.1.1 from c:\users\min\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

$ pip show flask
Name: Flask
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\min\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: Werkzeug, itsdangerous, Jinja2, click
Required-by: Flask-RESTful, Flask-API

$ pip show flask-restful
Name: Flask-RESTful
Version: 0.3.8
Summary: Simple framework for creating REST APIs
Home-page: https://www.github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/
Author: Twilio API Team
Author-email: help@twilio.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\min\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Requires: Flask, aniso8601, six, pytz
Required-by:
```

When I run the code, there is wrong in

```
from flask_restful import reqparse, Api, Resource
```

and error is

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name '_endpoint_from_view_func' from 'flask.helpers' (C:\Users\Min\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py)
  File "E:\yulin\python_project\image_text_project_-api\chuanxian_api_module_time_native2.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_restful import reqparse, Api, Resource
```

I don't know why, please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/pull/913

Comment: Thanks, @ewong, I find that installing the flask==1.12 version solved this problem. That is, just run "pip install flask==1.1.2" is ok.

Comment: They have fixed it: `Flask-RESTful==0.3.9` solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 31):

That's a known issue that awaits to be solved [here](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/pull/913).

In the meantime, I suggest a monkey patching:

```py
import flask.scaffold
flask.helpers._endpoint_from_view_func = flask.scaffold._endpoint_from_view_func
import flask_restful
...
```

For reference, the current version of my `Flask-RESTful` package is `0.3.8`.

---

**Edit**:

Since the issue has then been fixed in release `0.3.9`, just upgrade the package version:

```
Flask-RESTful>0.3.8
```

Comment: Thnxx :) it's really helpful!

Comment: After upgrading to version 0.3.9 I am getting `Segmentation fault` error. This is what I have installed - `Python 3.6.6 Flask 2.0.3 Werkzeug 2.0.3`

Comment: @renatodamas is the hero of the weekend :-) thanks! upgrades to 0.3.9

Answer (score 13):

Like Renato mentioned, this is a known issue.
The team has fixed it.
Using a recent version of `Flask-RESTful` fixed the issue for me.
For example:

```
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a monkey patch. You can define your own `_endpoint_from_view_func` or use `flask.scaffold._endpoint_from_view_func` as mentioned in answer of @RenatoDamas

```py
# monkey.py

def _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func):
    """Internal helper that returns the default endpoint for a given
    function.  This always is the function name.
    """
    assert view_func is not None, "expected view func if endpoint is not provided."
    return view_func.__name__


# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
def patch_restx(endpoint_from_view_func: bool = True) -> None:
    """
    Nasty hacks are here

    :param endpoint_from_view_func: Add missing function into flask for backward compatibility with `flask-restx`
    """
    if endpoint_from_view_func:
        func_name = "_endpoint_from_view_func"
        try:
            import pkg_resources
            packages = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key
            if "flask" in packages and "flask-restx" in packages:
                flask_version = tuple(map(int, packages["flask"].version.split(".")))
                flask_restx_version = tuple(map(int, packages["flask-restx"].version.split(".")))
                if (2, 0, 0) <= flask_version and (1, 0, 0) > flask_restx_version:
                    import flask
                    if not hasattr(flask.helpers, func_name):
                        setattr(flask.helpers, func_name, _endpoint_from_view_func)
        except ImportError:
            print(f"skipping monkey patch of {func_name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I just solved (or still trying to solve) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233291/importerror-while-trying-to-run-a-flask-app-in-a-virtual-environment-ubuntu-20)
Funny think is that I cannot get my server run without that "monkey" solution even with my flask_restful beign at 0.3.9.
I am not sure what is the issue, thank you for this thread though.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community. Comments should not be send as answers, I know it may be frustrating if you have yet to unlock the comment privileges. But you can always add more details to your answer to make it helpful for everyone.